# django iis6 with pyisapie and sqlite3 on production server

Tags: iis-6, sqlite, scalability

I am using Django on Windows 2003 Server SP2 and IIS 6 with pyisapi.

Do you recommend using sqlite3 on this production server?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using sqlite3 on a production server in general and especially on Windows 2003 Server.

Our application is an order management tool which will have 5 clients accessing it (not necessarily concurrently). It is only used on an intranet. For this purpose we have adjusted the admin interface to our needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is an excellent product. It's very simple to use and deploy, is very fast, highly reliable and doesn't typically require any external administration. It uses very few operating system resources, allowing you do better utilize the operating system and hardware resources that are available. SQLite is used by many projects.

You may also want to look into [Berkeley DB's SQL API](http://bit.ly/hY6MTm). It's completely SQLite compatible. In addition, it offers concurrency (multiple readers and writers active in the database), scalability (BDB manages databases in the 100's of GB to TB range today) and HA (High Availability either for load balancing or for hot standby with automatic failover) above and beyond what's currently available with SQLite.